# Handler.postAtTime vs Handler.postDelayed

Tags: java, android

The android [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class contains this method:

```
public final boolean postAtTime (Runnable r, Object token, long uptimeMillis)
```

to post a Runnable at a given time. The `token` can be used later to remove the callback to `r` from the message queue thanks to this method:

```
public final void removeCallbacks (Runnable r, Object token)
```

The following method **doesn't exist** in the Handler class

```
public final boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, Object token, long delay)
```

Is there a good reason for not providing such a method?

Comment: What are you missing there? The token?

Comment: yes the token and so the ability the remove callback to something that was posted with postDelayed

Comment: You can always call `Handler.removeCallbacks()` with your Runnable. Works excellently if you ask me.

Comment: That's a good question. I find it odd that the documentation for what "token" is supposed to be other than an identifier for what Runnables you want to remove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the source code, the token object eventually passes to the Message:

```
public final boolean postAtTime(Runnable r, Object token, long uptimeMillis)
308    {
309        return sendMessageAtTime(getPostMessage(r, token), uptimeMillis);
310    }

private static Message getPostMessage(Runnable r, Object token) {
608        Message m = Message.obtain();
609        m.obj = token;
```

And postDelay

```
 public final boolean postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)
330    {
331        return sendMessageDelayed(getPostMessage(r), delayMillis);
332    }
```

If what you want is

```
public final boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, Object token, long delay)
```

Then why not just use

```
public final boolean postAtTime (Runnable r, Object token, long uptimeMillis)
```

since its the same.

**Update, forgot to add this:**

```
public final boolean sendMessageDelayed(Message msg, long delayMillis)
442    {
443        if (delayMillis < 0) {
444            delayMillis = 0;
445        }
446        return sendMessageAtTime(msg, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + delayMillis);
447    }
```

Comment: ok... so it seems there is no good reason to not have `postDelayed (Runnable r, Object token, long delay)` in the API

Comment: Yes, but you can always suggest it to the Android groups.

Comment: From what it looks like, the token object was an afterthought in the Handler class so the class is somewhat incomplete.

Comment: @ben75 After few years later: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Object,%20long)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Handler source, it appears that there is :

```
private final Message getPostMessage(Runnable r, Object token) {
    Message m = Message.obtain();
    m.obj = token;
    m.callback = r;
    return m;
}
```

Which can be copied for what you want : Instead of calling `postDelayed`, wrap your runnable in such a message

```
sendMessageDelayed(getPostMessage(r, token), delayMillis);
```

you can then use `removeCallbacks()` with token as param

Comment: But it requires you to handle messages, which is something I rarely do because it means I can't use the Handler right out of the box.

Comment: yes you can. the message will indeed reach Handler.handleMessage, but the default implementation is to run the Message.callback. if you look at the code for Handler.post(Runnable), it creates a message in the same fashion I posted

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but the `postDelayed` method version taking a token as an argument was added in API **28**: see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Object,%20long)

For older API versions one still has to use `postAtTime` if a token is required to remove the callback later.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a postDelayed runnable r from a handler H, just call H.removeCallbacks(r). Why do you need a token?

Comment: As far as I understand, the token allow you to select only some callbacks to r (if the runnable is posted multiple times)

Comment: Ok I see, if you really need this token with a postDelayed runnable, you could extend the Handler class to add a token attribute and create your own postDelayed method with this token :/